# How to check if laptop supports mSATA?

Tags: laptop, bios, dell-inspiron, msata

I have Dell inspiron 7520 laptop which has two configurations with mSATA connection and preinstalled mSATA card and without mSATA connection. Mine is without preinstalled mSATA card, but I found in bios

> mSATA Device : [Not detected]

So does that mean my laptop supports mSATA (but it is empty) or this is just some error, and is there a way to check if my laptop has support for mSATA withou pulling it apart ?

Comment: Your conclusion is likely correct.  You would have to check the manual for your model to verify of course.

Answer (score 1):

> So does that mean my laptop supports mSATA (but it is empty) or this is just some error, and is there a way to check if my laptop has support for mSATA withou pulling it apart ?

If your Model is dell Insperion 7520/15R (SE) - then yes.

You should head to the [dell.com/support-forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19458679.aspx) that has this question and answer. It states (with some added numbers and (SE) to the model from yours):

[image: mSata]